# Expo - Standalone App Crashing on Splash Screen

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have created an app in React Native / Expo. It works fine during development but is crashing when I create a standalone app (`expo build:android`)

The splash screen gets displayed and then directly the app crashes.

This is not an issue of the Expo CLI, because I tried to build other apps and they seem to work fine.

[Code](https://github.com/dipamsen/DigiSchool-App)
[APK Build Download](https://exp-shell-app-assets.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/android/%40dipamsen/digischool-376a3989451c4546a03f2789df8b8a44-signed.apk)

Here are the [Expo APK Build Log Files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1do_jQey8uMPVoi2PSFtyCAzVbz_wj2Ks/view?usp=sharing), I didn't get any other way to share this

Comment: look for the relevant lines in the logs and please share them

Comment: There doesn't seem any error or weird lines in the log, @DavidThery

Comment: @FunPlanet , Did you get any solution ? I am facing the same issue. Please help if you have find any solution for it.

Comment: @ZabihUllah i am facing the same issue  .Please help if you have find any solution for it